# Using constexpr in a namespace with static_assert is giving error

Tags: c++, c++11

I have declared the following in header file.

```
namespace G1
{
    inline namespace V1
    {
        constexpr float getV();
    }
}
```

In CPP file, I have defined the `getV` function as

```
constexpr float G1::V1::getV()
{
    return 0.1f;
}
```

In the main I am using `static_assert` to compare the version as shown.

```
int main()
{
    static_assert( G1::getV() == 1.0f, "Error"); // Please Ignore the way I am comparing the floats
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the code, I am getting `expression did not evaluate to a constant`.

Am I doing anything wrong here? I am using VS2015.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `==` instead of `=` to compare.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I modified the compare.

Comment: Are both functions in the same file? Otherwise, how is the `main` function supposed to know what `getV()` returns?

Comment: @BoPersson: I have included the header, the one in which I have declared the namespace and also the function declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, the C++ compilation model is 2 phase.  First you compile, then you link.

`constexpr` only works in the compile phase.  There is no requirement that compilers can fold `constexpr` function bodies into call sites when doing so would require link-time `constexpr` evaluation.

So when you fail to provide a body for your `constexpr` function, anyone that cannot see that body *will not evaluate it at compile time*, but rather wait until runtime.

`constexpr` doesn't mean "will be run at compile time", but rather "could be run at compile time in some situations".

Answer (score 2):

If you want the compiler compiling `main` to know about the value `getV` returns *at compile time*, you must implement the function in the header too.
Since you use `static_assert` the definition is needed at compile time.

The way you do it only the compiler of the .cpp file containing `getV` can know what it returns. This is usually a different compiler call.

By link time, it is too late to check the `static_assert`.

The error message: `expression did not evaluate to a constant` is caused by the compiler not knowing the implementation. In a "runtime" context it would insert a call here, to be later fixed up by the linker and executed at runtime. A runtime call is however never a compile time constant.